# RegEx Find and Replace in Sublime Text

Tags: c#, regex, sublimetext2

So I have a large file with the following types of lines:

```
public static string SyncButton = StringsProxy.GetStringByKey ("SyncButton") ?? "SYNC";
```

I need to replace this with the following version

```
public static string SyncButton { 
get { 
    if (_SyncButton == null) { 
        _SyncButton = StringsProxy.GetStringByKey ("SyncButton") ?? "SYNC"; 
    }
    return _SyncButton;
}
set { 
    _SyncButton = value;
}
}
```

Can someone help construct a regular expression that could do a find and replace like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this thing as regex:

```
public static string (.+?) = StringsProxy.GetStringByKey \("(.+?)"\) \?\? "(.+?)";
```

with this one:

```
  public static string \1 { 
get { 
    if (_\1 == null) { 
        _\1 = StringsProxy.GetStringByKey ("\1") ?? "\3"; 
    }
    return _\1;
}
set { 
    _\1 = value;
}
}
```

Example:

[image: example]!

Answer (score 1):

try this

Find What:

```
public static string ([^= ]*) (= StringsProxy\.GetStringByKey \("SyncButton"\) \?\? "SYNC";)
```

Replace With:

```
public static string \1 { 
get { 
    if (_\1 == null) { 
        _\1 = \2
    }
    return _\1;
}
set { 
    _\1 = value;
}
}
```